# Two prisoners look at each other through the prison bars

Tags: situation

Two prisoners look at each other through the prison bars. Which one of 'em is free?

Comment: Hello @savoit902. Welcome to PSE. A very short puzzle (without any explanation), can bring a lot of speculative answers. Unless of course you are absolutely certain that there is only one (or two) logical answers. Please consider this. Otherwise the puzzle may get flagged for closing. BTW there is a famous quote by Dale Carnegy (?) with similar line and ends up with One saw mud and the other.....

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> neither is free

because

> they are both prisoners. Prisoners are by definition not free.